# Apache Tomcat Startup error : during deploying web application

Tags: java, sql-server, apache, hibernate, tomcat

I'm trying to startup tomcate 5.5 I get this error below.

```
    Hibernate: 
  delete 
 from
    LOCKS 
where
    SERVER_ID=?
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(CustomObjectInputStream.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:362)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4196)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:980)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)

Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager start
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(CustomObjectInputStream.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:362)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4196)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:980)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)

Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.apache.webapp.balancer.BalancerFilter: init(): ruleChain: [org.apache.webapp.balancer.RuleChain: [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.URLStringMatchRule: Target string: News / Redirect URL: http://www.cnn.com], [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.RequestParameterRule: Target param name: paramName / Target param value: paramValue / Redirect URL: http://www.yahoo.com], [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.AcceptEverythingRule: Redirect URL: http://jakarta.apache.org]]
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doLoad
SEVERE: IOException while loading persisted sessions: java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(CustomObjectInputStream.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:362)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4196)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:980)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)

Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager start
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2794)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(CustomObjectInputStream.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:362)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:321)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.start(StandardManager.java:637)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.setManager(ContainerBase.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4196)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:980)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1203)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1022)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)

Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:41 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:41 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:41 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:41 PM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
Feb 05, 2016 12:16:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 54142 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

The said error might occur when the server is not properly shutdown.

When we load our application on server the jsp and the resulting compiled classes reside in the ***work directory*** of Tomcat. Tomcat preserves the *server state* when it  is shutdown. After an improper shutdown, the next time you run your application, Tomcat tries to look for **SESSION.ser** i.e. server session and hence you get the mentioned error.

You can find your tomcat work directory on following path:

```
[workspace]\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work
```

Deleting all the contents of the ***work***  folder will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue where the application suddenly wouldn't start one morning in `Tomcat 9`. I had to delete the contents of the `work/Catalina/localhost/` folder in tomcat root.

```
root@appserver:/tomcat9/app# ls -ltr work/Catalina/localhost/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 app app  6 Feb  9  2021 ROOT
drwxr-xr-x 2 app app  6 Feb  9  2021 manager
drwxr-xr-x 2 app app  6 Feb  9  2021 host-manager
drwxr-xr-x 2 app app  6 Feb  9  2021 examples
drwxr-xr-x 2 app app  6 Feb  9  2021 docs
drwxr-x--- 2 app app  6 Mar 23 09:27 nsl#editor##2.0.43
drwxr-x--- 2 app app  6 Mar 23 09:28 app
drwxr-x--- 2 app app 40 Mar 23 09:41 probe
root@appserver:/tomcat9/app# rm -rf  work/Catalina/localhost/*
root@appserver:/tomcat9/app# ls -ltr work/Catalina/localhost/
```